# Running time of a loop up to i*i <= n

Tags: algorithm, square-root, big-o

Here is the code:

```
int foo(int n)
{
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    int f = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i*i<=n; i++)
        if(n%i == 0)
            f+=2;
    i--;
    if(i*i == n)
        f--;
    return f;
}
```

My problem is that I cannot determine Θ for this for loop,
I think it's square-root(n) but is there an order named square root n?

My answer is:
Theta(sqrt(n)) because of this loop

```
for(i=1; i*i<=n; i++)
```

`i * i <= n` take sqrt for both sides

`i <= sqrt(n)`

Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @JackKrauser To have this question fit better into the Q&A model (as "Your analysis is correct" doesn't make for a particularly good answer), I suggest you change this question into asking something like "What's the running time complexity of this loop?" and then post an answer with your analysis, which you then accept.

Answer (score 1):

O(sqrt n) looks weird but right to me

Comment: it's polynomial growth not quadratic ( i++ ) ??

Comment: Any power of n is a viable power of complexity. O(n^1/2) is fine.